# Mysql не работает ограничение целостности check constraint

Tags: mysql

Пытаюсь запретить записывать нулевые значения в поле datetime

```
ALTER TABLE test
ADD CONSTRAINT chk_dt CHECK (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dt) != 0)
```

Не работает. Таблица уже создана

Comment: К сожалению и не будет. MySQL не поддерживает check только для совместимости с другими БД умеет не ругаться на синтаксис

Answer (score 0):

> The CHECK clause is parsed but **ignored** by all storage engines.

[Документация](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html)

Можете попробовать организовать требуемую проверку в формате триггера.